# Trigger event when a each div has been scrolled into view and update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have one of my React components fire an event every time one of the children components have been scrolled into view. To do this I am passing refs from the children up to the parent then comparing the position of the window the the "currentCard's" ref. Once the window reaches the bottom of the currentCard it adds 1 to the state of the currentCard. The problem is that when I setState it doesn't happen fast enough so the scroll event fires multiple setStates then goes out of bounds. Here is how I am handling the scrolling:

```
componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => this.handleScroll(e))
}

handleScroll = (e) => {
    let { cardRefs, currentCard } = this.state;
    let currentCardPos = cardRefs[currentCard].current.getBoundingClientRect().height

    if ( window.pageYOffset >= currentCardPos ){
      console.log('bottom')
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        currentCard: prevState.currentCard + 1
      }))
    }
}
```

cardRefs is the array of refs passed up from the children components and currentCard is just an index to keep track of what card the user is currently on on the page.

There has to be a better way of doing this I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are using `getBoundingClientRect().height` which is always going to be a constant. For example if the height is set as 500px, it always returns 500px. After window.offsetY crosses 500px it keeps incrementing until it goes out of bounds.

Instead, you can try to use `getBoundingClientRect().bottom`. When the value goes negative, it means its out of viewport and you can set the state to next element.

An example SO snippet added below. You can scroll down and see the state update in console as soon as an element goes out of view. Hope this helps!

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { cardRefs: [], currentCard: 0 };
  myRef1 = React.createRef();
  myRef2 = React.createRef();
  myRef3 = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    this.setState({
      cardRefs: [this.myRef1, this.myRef2, this.myRef2]
    });
  }

  handleScroll = () => {
    let { cardRefs, currentCard } = this.state;
    if (cardRefs[currentCard].current.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < 0) {
      console.log("bottom");
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          currentCard:
            currentCard + 1 >= cardRefs.length
              ? cardRefs.length - 1
              : currentCard + 1
        };
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    console.log("Current Card", this.state.currentCard);
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          ref={this.myRef1}
          style={{ height: "500px", backgroundColor: "red" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          ref={this.myRef2}
          style={{ height: "500px", backgroundColor: "green" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          ref={this.myRef3}
          style={{ height: "500px", backgroundColor: "blue" }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```